# tinymce changing urls

Tags: php, tinymce

I have tinyMCE on a simple text file editor, but when i enter a url that is the same as the server, and include the text file through php, it reads http://../directory, instead of http://www.domain.com/directory.

Comment: i defeated it by instead of entering the URL in tincMCE, i used the placeholder [[URL]], and then str_replace to switch out the place holder with the URL. Works fine.

Comment: try this option: http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/relative_urls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tinyMCE URLs are generally pretty tricky, but manageable. They have a whole section dedicated to making them work [here](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:FAQ#Paths.2FURLs_are_incorrect.2C_I_want_absolute.2Frelative_URLs.3F).

Essentially you need to add two settings to your config file

```
tinyMCE.init({
    relative_urls : false,
    document_base_url : "http://www.site.com/path1/"
});
```

That should rewrite all your URLs using the base url, avoiding the relative `../`s